# change value of bind in a list when triggered vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm very new to **vue js**. I tried passing parameter to get the index of the list when clicked but i still can't update it's attribute value.

I want to update the value of `isState` to "1" when click

**This is my list**

```
<li v-for="(link, index) in links">
    <a :state="isState" 
    @click="onlink_click(link.link_text,index)">

    {{link.link_text}}

    </a>
</li>
```

**Event Handling**

```
methods: {
 onlink_click(this_link,index){
  this.links[index].isState = "1" }
```

**Data**

```
data (){
 return {
isState: "0",
links : [
{link_text :"Home"},
{link_text:"About"},
{link_text:"Porfolio"},
{link_text:"Contact"}]  }
}
```

Comment: There are no isState property into the links array - http://jsbin.com/wuhiwufoye/edit?html,js,console,output does this works for you ?

Comment: what I want is when i click the "home" link it will suppose to update its own `isState` and it wont affect the other list

Comment: Yep but each object into the links array has only link_text property - you should defined new property for each object called isState

Comment: I see,thanks!... is there a way to check its index and update the object called `isState`?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hehepileli/edit?html,js,console,output does this works for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Belmin Bedak suggestion you will probably want to do this:

```
data() {
  return {
    ...
    links: [
        { 
            link_text: "Home",
            isState: 0
        },
        ...
    ]
  }
}
```

And then in on click you can do this

```
onClickMethod: function ( text ) {
  this.links.find( link => link.link_text === text ).isState = 1
}
```